# Scripting enterprise architect: change element compartment visibility

Tags: scripting, enterprise-architect

Is it possible to change element notes visibility in script? I.e. to perform in script the same action as [Ctrl-Shift-Y]-[Show notes]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but not directly.

```
style = oldStyle + "Notes=100;"
Repository.Execute("UPDATE t_diagramobjects SET ObjectStyle=" + style + " WHERE InstanceID=" + instanceId)
```

assuming you have the `instanceId` of the diagram object you want to change. Also `oldStyle` has the current contents `ObjectStyle`, it ends with a semicolon and does not already contain a "Notes=;" string.